# info on firmware upgrade

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, device-firmware

My Asus Eee transformer just received a firmware update. Where can I go to check what the update included? Asus' website isn't helpful. I'm on 8.6.5.19, and I've already noticed the market place is different, id like to know any other cool features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this [thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1041502) to very helpful.

The entire forum for the Transformer on XDA has a lot of information.

Comment: Great thread!  Thanks I found it very interesting.