# What's in an update?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, device-firmware

My Samsung Galaxy S2 just updated to version `I9100XWKI4`. Is there a place where I can see what's in that update? And in the ones before that?

All I could find was a [blog post](http://www.dialandroid.com/2011/09/install-i9100xwki4i9100xxki1-android.html) from a site that shows how to root the device. Isn't there an official change log somewhere?

Comment: For the ASUS Transformer tablet I found via a post here, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/info-on-firmware-upgrade I guess you are looking for the analog for your device.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [Google Changes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html) for each release of android, but this device uses Samsung TouchWiz. This release contains the Google changes, plus the changes that Samsung made. I do not know of a "change log" page that Samsung has.

I read that this version is the official Gingerbread 2.3.5 release of Android TouchWiz. But also, if you use a USB Jig, that it breaks the that functionality.